# [$injector:unpr Unknown provider: GammeProvider <- Gamme <- GammeEditCtrl

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

Hello I am writing my first angular test with Jasmine but I keep getting the error
here is my controller

```
(function () {
    'use strict';
    var dependencies = [];
    angular.module('entityEdit', dependencies)
            .config(configFn)
            .run(runFn)
            .directive('entityEdit', ['BASE_PATH', entityEditDirective])
            .controller('EntityEditCtrl', ['$scope', '$rootScope','Entity', EntityEditCtrl])

    function EntityEditCtrl($scope, $rootScope,Entity) {
        $scope.entity = {};
        $scope.list=[
            {'id':"1",'libelle':'A' },
            {'id':"2",'libelle':'B' },
        ]
        $rootScope.$on('Entity_LIST_SELECTED', function (event, data) {
            console.log("received");
            $scope.entity = data;
        });
        $scope.save= saveFn;             
        function saveFn()
        {
            console.log("savefn");
            console.log($scope.entity);
            Entity.updateEntity($scope.entity);
        }
    }
    function runFn() {
        console.log('Run : entityEdit');
    }
    function configFn() {
        console.log('Config : entityEdit');
    }
})();
```

and here is my jasmine test

```
describe('EntityEditCtrl', function () {
    var $rootScope, scope, $controller;
    beforeEach(angular.mock.module('entityEdit'));
    beforeEach(inject(function ($rootScope, $controller) {
        scope = $rootScope.$new();
        $controller('EntityEditCtrl', {
        $scope: scope
    });     
    ctrl = $controller('EntityEditCtrl',function(){});
    }));    
    it('exists',inject(function($controller){   
             expect(ctrl).toBeDefined();    
             expect(ctrl).not.toBeNull();
             expect(typeof ctrl).toBe('object');
    }));
});
```

If you see the problem please let me know

Comment: The error complains about GammeEditCtrl. You're showing us the test of EntityEditCtrl. Show us your REAL code, and the REAL and COMPLETE error message.

Comment: There is something missing or your're not explaining everything :P: Where is GammeEditCtrl?

Comment: Sorry please read it Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: EntityProvider <- Entity <- EntityEditCtrl
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.8/$injector/unpr?p0=EntityProvider%20%3C-%20Entity%20%3C-%20EntityEditCtrl in the title

Comment: Well, your controller depends on a service names Entity. Where and how is it defined?

Comment: In an other js file named core.entity.js

(function () {
    angular.module('core.entity', [])

            .config(configFunction)
            .run(runFunction)
            .service('Entity', ['$http', Entity])

    function Entity($http) {
        this.loadList = function (offset, limit) {
            return $http.get('/catalogue/entity/list-json',{'params':{'offset':offset,'limit':limit}});
        };
})();

Comment: OK. So it's defined in another module named 'core.entity'. Do you load that module in your test? Or does the module you load in your test depend on that module?

Comment: I loaded core.entity.js in specRunner.html  and the problem still persist; it seems that I should find the way how to resolve dependencies between modules. !

Comment: Your test does `angular.mock.module('entityEdit')`, so it loads the 'entityEdit' module. Does it do the same thing with the module 'core.entity'? Or have you specified that 'entityEdit' had a dependency on 'core.entity' in `angular.module('entityEdit', dependencies)`? I'm not playing with you here. Just trying to let you figure out the problem and think about how things work by yourself.

Comment: Yes you have right  we should moke also core.entity

Comment: module() doesn't *mock* the module. It *loads* it and configures the injector with all the components declared in that module (and its dependencies, recursively)

Answer (score 1):

unit testing and if you want to test a specific unit you need to inject every module that is required inside that unit and over here missing module is entity.

```
describe('EntityEditCtrl', function () {
var $rootScope, scope, controller,Entity;
beforeEach(angular.mock.module(core.entity'));
beforeEach(angular.mock.module('entityEdit'));
beforeEach(inject(function ($rootScope, $controller,_Entity_) {
    scope = $rootScope.$new();
    Entity=_Entity_;
    controller=$controller('EntityEditCtrl', {$scope: scope});     
    }));    
it('exists',inject(function($controller){   
         expect(ctrl).toBeDefined();    
         expect(ctrl).not.toBeNull();
         expect(typeof ctrl).toBe('object');
}));
});
```

Comment: we should  also add :beforeEach(angular.mock.module(core.entity'));

Comment: @Abdelhak not sure why you accepted this answer, since it fails to do what would fix the error you're asking about (and doesn't give any explanation).

Comment: This answer resolve module dependencies , still to add (beforeEach(angular.mock.module(core.entity'));)

Comment: No, it doesn't. What solves it is the missing loading of the 'core.entity' module. Other than that, your original code is fine, and adding an Entity variable and an _Entity_ argument is completely useless in the code posed in this answer.

Comment: just added the entity module and updated the answer and the problem was with entity module.

Comment: first of all it is unit testing and if you want to test a specific unit you need to inject every module that is required inside that unit.

Comment: @vikash agreed, but that explanation should be in the answer, not in the comment. And most importantly, the code should indeed load the 'core.entity' module, since it is required by the controller under test. The code in your answer doesn't do that, which violates the principle you just enunciated, and is the cause of the OP's problem.

Comment: @JBNizet I agree with you but i considered specific part of the problem that is with the entity module and answered accordingly.

Comment: The specific problem the OP asked about is not solved, nor explained, by your answer. Why don't you just fix your answer by adding the missing module loading line of code and an explanation?

Comment: I guess updated answer is enough to solve the problem.